# in ionic app , how to align combobox with text fields in a row

Tags: html, css, angular, ionic-framework, alignment

as you can see in this image

[image]

my html code is this:

```
       <ion-row>
        <ion-col>
          <ion-item>
            <searchable-ion-select isModal="true" name="country" valueField="code" [(ngModel)]="country" title="Country"
              (onChange)="countrySelected()" textField="name" [items]="countries">
            </searchable-ion-select>
          </ion-item>
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col>
          <ion-item>
            <ion-label class="item-name" stacked>Phone number*</ion-label>
            <ion-input [(ngModel)]="phone" (ngModelChange)="onFieldChanged()" type="text" required name="phoneNumber"></ion-input>
          </ion-item>
          <ion-row *ngIf="!isPhoneFormat && false">
            Invalid format!
          </ion-row>
        </ion-col>
        <ion-row *ngIf="!isNameFormat && false">
          Invalid format for first name or last name
        </ion-row>
      </ion-row>
```

these are not in a row but **first name last name** in a row

```
      <ion-row>
        <ion-col>
          <ion-item>
            <ion-label class="item-name" stacked>First name*</ion-label>
            <ion-input [(ngModel)]="firstName" (ngModelChange)="onFieldChanged()" type="text" required name="firstName"></ion-input>
          </ion-item>
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col>
          <ion-item>
            <ion-label class="item-name" stacked>Last name*</ion-label>
            <ion-input [(ngModel)]="lastName" (ngModelChange)="onFieldChanged()" type="text" required name="lastName"></ion-input>
          </ion-item>
        </ion-col>
        <ion-row *ngIf="!isNameFormat && false">
          Invalid format for first name or last name
        </ion-row>
      </ion-row>
```

how can i align **searchable-ion-select** with **ion-label and his ion-input**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a CSS Problem
Because of the labels above the ion-input's they are lower than the selects. You need to add some margin-top to the ion-selects. Just read up on CSS, it's very important for styling ionic apps.

if you don't want to use CSS you could add a label above the ion-select, or remove the label from the inputs, but you will need CSS in the future anyways.

Answer (score 0):

this css:

```
.select-searchable{
    padding-top: 3px;
    border: 2px solid #cfcfcf;
    border-radius: 8px;
    margin-top: 19px;
}

.select-searchable-label,.select-searchable-value{
    margin: 7px !important;
}
```

css can applied what i need.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

i think in this case using the

```
<ion-grid>
  <ion-row>
    <ion-col col-6>This column will take 6 columns</ion-col>
    <ion-col col-6>This column will take 6 columns</ion-col>
  </ion-row>
</ion-grid>
```

would help and the put the width of the input field in in percentage so that it can scale to the current current size of the `ion-col`.